# How to make "Done" button close keyboard

Tags: objective-c, button, keyboard

I need help making it so that when you open the keyboard, the "Done" button will close out the keyboard. P.S. I already have it so that the keyboard has the "Done" button. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using a `UITextField`, a `UITextView`, or something else?

Comment: Also, is this iOS or OSX?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS use resignFirstResponder

```
[textView resignFirstResponder]
[textField resignFirstResponder]
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add an listener on your edit:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            // Dismiss the keyboard here.
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```